# "defined component" is not a known element inside a route component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-router

I'm new to `angular` - coming from `vue.js/nuxt` background -, and still trying to get my head around the concept of angular modules.

I'm trying to make a structure of an E-commerce website for only learning purposes. I don't know if this is right, but here is the structure I'm working on.

```css
/app
    app.module.ts (1)
    app-routing.module.ts (2)
    ...

    /modules
        products/
            products.module.ts (3)
            products-routing.module.ts (4)
            products-page/
                products-page.module.ts (5)
                products-page.component.html (7)   <--- (... inside this)
                products-page.component.ts
                ...

                components/
                    shop-banner/
                        shop-banner.component.html
                        shop-banner.component.ts (6)   <--- (show this ...)
                        ...

                    categories-list/
                    products-list/
                    ...
                    
                    

            single-product-page/
            ...

        auth/
        orders/
        ...
```

and here are the files of the above structure:

`app.module` (1):

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
// ...

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule, // <<<<<< router >>>>>>
    // ...
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  exports: []
})
export class AppModule { }
```

`app-route.module` (2):

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
// ...

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'auth',
    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/auth/auth-routing.module')
      .then(module => module.AuthRoutingModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'products',
    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/products/products.module')
      .then(module => module.ProductsModule)  // <<<<<< ProductsModule >>>>>>
  },
  {
    path: 'orders',
    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/orders/orders-routing.module')
      .then(module => module.OrdersRoutingModule)
  },
  // ....
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

`products.module` (3)

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ProductsRoutingModule } from './products-routing.module';
import { ProductsPageModule } from './products-page/products-page.module';
// ...

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ProductsPageModule,     // <<< Components that will be used inside ProductsPage >>>
    ProductsRoutingModule,  // <<<<<< Products Router >>>>>>
    // ...
  ]
})
export class ProductsModule { }
```

`products-routing.module.ts` (4)

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ProductsPageComponent } from './products-page/products-page.component';
import { SingleProductComponent } from './single-product-page/single-product.component';
// ...

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ProductsPageComponent,   // <<< products-page.component >>>
  },
  {
    path: ':id',
    component: SingleProductComponent
  },
  // ...
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)]
})
export class ProductsRoutingModule { }
```

`products-page.module.ts` (5)

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { CategoriesListComponent } from './components/categories-list/categories-list.component';
import { ProductsListComponent } from './components/products-list/products-list.component';
import { ShopBannerComponent } from './components/shop-banner/shop-banner.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ShopBannerComponent,
    // ...
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    ShopBannerComponent,
    // ...
  ]
})
export class ProductsPageModule { }
```

`shop-banner.component.ts` (6)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-shop-banner',
  templateUrl: './shop-banner.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./shop-banner.component.scss']
})
export class ShopBannerComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

`products-page.component.html` (7)

```html
<app-shop-banner></app-shop-banner>
```

> inside this file I got the error:
>
> `'app-shop-banner' is not a known element`

before splitting the `ShopBannerComponent`, everything was working as expected:

[image]

Comment: At first glance it looks like you haven't declared the `ProductsPageComponent` in any NgModule.

Comment: In which module have you declared `ProductsPageComponent`? It has to be declared in the same module as `ShopBannerComponent`, or module where the `ProductsPageComponent` is declared has to import `ProductsPageModule` (because `ShopBannerComponent` is declared there).

Comment: Oh no, I've spent the whole night suffering from this bug XD, thanks a lot.